# Can I discover the format of archive?

Tags: archive, split, cat

Not long I have decided to make a compress of my archives .deb / tar.gz, on only one archive. No problem I compress, and I used split command to break that archive in many parts to (upload - backup) and works fine, but the problem is, I forgot what the format of the compress that I used. And now, I don't know how to join the parts. I can anything to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join file:

```
cat split1 split2 split3 > myfile
```

To find out archive format, you can use **file(1)**.

For example:

```
housezet@arch: ~
$ file ufw-0.33
ufw-0.33: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sat Aug 18 06:12:49 2012
```

Comment: Hello,! the command that you suggest works fine, but I have an problem, with the archive I get this...
`gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
`
I tried to extract with this command `tar -zxvf myfilee`, two packages are ready, but the others no... :/ you can help me ?

Comment: Maybe some parts are missed? Filename following **cat** should be put in order, such as **cat xaa xab xac > data**.

Comment: I do... `cat aa*> myfile`, but doesn't work. So I do with you said but is the same...